# iOS bug: rotated view gets clipped by background image

Tags: ios, react-native

If I rotate a view in the out-of-plane direction (rotateX or rotateY transform) the view goes "behind" the background and gets clipped. Happens only on iOS (works fine on Android). Is this a bug or is there some way to prevent this? I tried setting the zIndex and doesn't solve it.

Repro:

```
import {ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const image = {uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Sand.jpg'};

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ImageBackground source={image} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>LOL</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 100,
    textAlign: 'center',
    transform: [
      { perspective: 300 },
      { rotateX: '30deg'},
    ],
  },
});

export default App;
```

[image: screenshot of problem]